# Inner product exterior algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products, orthonormal, exterior-algebra

I have to prove that if $V$ is a real vector space ($\dim V=n$) with inner product $(.,.)$ then if we define
 $$
 (v_{1}\wedge v_{2}\wedge\cdots\wedge v_{k},w_{1}\wedge w_{2}\wedge\cdots\wedge w_{k}) =\det((a_{j,r})_{j,r=1,\dots,k}),
 $$
 where $a_{j,r}=(v_{j},v_{r})$, and we extend it by linearity  it defines an inner product on  $\Lambda^{k}V$. Same question in the hermitian case.

I have proved that $(v_{1}\wedge v_{2}\wedge...\wedge v_{k},v_{1}\wedge v_{2}\wedge...\wedge v_{k}) \ge0 $ and it is zero iff $v_{1}\wedge v_{2}\wedge...\wedge v_{k} = 0$. but what about a generic element of $\Lambda^{k}V$ that is linear combination of "simple" elements?  thank you!

Comment: Use an orthonormal basis.

Comment: can you be more explicit please?I have to consider an orthonormal basis $\{e_{i}\} $ and then prove that  $(e_{i_{1}}\wedge e_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge e_{i_{k}}, i_{1}<i_{2}..<i_{k} ) is an orthonormal basis of the exterior algebra?

Comment: Yes! (Or "orthogonal" both times -- this is a bit better.)

Comment: so  $$
 (e_{i_{1}}\wedge e_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge e_{i_{k}},e_{i_{1}}\wedge e_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge e_{i_{k}}) =det(identity matrix KxK)
 $$

Comment: but why $$(e_{i_{1}}\wedge e_{i_{2}}\wedge...\wedge e_{i_{k}},e_{j_{1}}\wedge e_{j_{2}}\wedge...\wedge e_{j_{k}})=0 $$?

Comment: Just look at the matrix. I'm claiming that it always has a row full of zeroes unless $\left(i_1,i_2,...,i_k\right) = \left(j_1,j_2,...,j_k\right)$.

Comment: I am working on (almost) the same problem and am farther behind than you in understanding it. (It's one of my first problems involving exterior algebra).  Would you mind sharing your proof that the thing-we-hope-is-an-inner-product is positive-definite? I'm hoping that will help me understand how the definitions fit together. Thank you.