# Is there a name for the "two-argument" Gramian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

Let $V=(V, \langle\; , \; \rangle)$ denote an inner product space. Then the concept "Gramian matrix" is the function \begin{align*}V^n &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \\x &\mapsto \sum_{i,j=1}^n \langle x_i,x_j\rangle e_i e_j^\top.\end{align*}

Suppose we're interested in the two-argument version of this, namely \begin{align*}V^n \times V^n &\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \\ (x,y) &\mapsto \sum_{i,j=1}^n \langle x_i,y_j\rangle e_i e_j^\top. \end{align*}

The determinant of this matrix shows up in the definition of the [dot product of multivectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1028122/inner-product-exterior-algebra).

> **Question.** Does this function $V^n \times V^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ have a name and/or accepted notation, like "two-argument Gram matrix" or something like that?
>
> Also, is there an accepted notation for it?

Comment: Where did you find this definition of gramian matrix (the ordinary "single-argument")? $x_i$ and $x_j$ are components of $x$? Then what is it meant by $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$?

Comment: @trying, that's the inner product. You can think of this as $x_i \bullet y_j$. Look up "inner product space." Note that, since $x$ is a list of vectors, hence $x_i$ is a vector, not a a scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant in the question you cited is called cross-gramian. See [here](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/%7Etsirel/Courses/Analysis4-Fall2015/lect6.pdf).

Correspondingly the matrix is called **cross-gramian operator** or **cross-gram matrix** as is reported in "Bridging erasures and the infrastructure
of frames" a chapter of *R. Balan et al. (eds.) - Excursions in Harmonic Analysis, Volume 4*

There also the notation used are these:
$$Gr(x,y)=(\langle x_i,y_j\rangle)_{i,j} = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \langle x_i,y_j\rangle e_i \otimes e_j$$

I think that $x^Ty$ could conveniently be used, generalizing the notation of the gramian matrix given in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).